# Python equivalent for Perl's pack(H*, $string)

Tags: python, pack

Does anybody know how to take an arbitrary long hex string (e.g. `"01020304deadbeef"`) and obtain the corresponding bytes (`"\x01\x02\x03\x04\xde\xad\xbe\xef"`)? In Perl, this can be obtained using `pack('H*', $string)`, but I'm looking for a Python solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> T = (1, 2, 3)
>>> struct.pack('H' * len(T), *T)
'\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00'
```

**EDIT:**

```
>>> "01020304deadbeef".decode('hex')
'\x01\x02\x03\x04\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
```

Comment: I can't seem to do test = struct.pack('H' * len(T), *T). When i try to print out "test" it's empty. :(

Comment: You mean it's unprintable. Print its `repr()` instead.

Comment: For any confused people that's print repr(test). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Real quick if you have a second, This isn't working for me and I was wondering if you know why

string = "hello world"
T = tuple(string)
struct.pack('H' * len(T), *T)

struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer

Comment: @JaronBradley: "H" is for `unsigned short`s. If you want to pack a `char` then you need to use ["c"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters). Or you can just use "s" or "p" for the whole string.

Comment: Given @ikegami's edit, this answer seems wrong. It takes integers and turns each one into two bytes. The question wants to take a string of hexidecimal digits and produce a sequence of bytes, one for every two characters of hex.